# Create a MustOverride Property with Reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

Can anyone tell me how I would create a `MustOverride` property using Reflection?

Comment: I either don't understand this question or the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean with `Reflection.Emit`? If so, you use `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`, with `MethodAttributes.Abstract`.

Here's an example; in `Bar.Method` is `abstract`; `Bar2.Method` overrides it.

```
    AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName("Foo");
    var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var module = asm.DefineDynamicModule("Foo");
    var type = module.DefineType("Bar", TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass);
    var method = type.DefineMethod("Method", MethodAttributes.Abstract | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
        CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);

    var final = type.CreateType();

    type = module.DefineType("Bar2", TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass, final);
    var method2 = type.DefineMethod("Bar", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
        CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
    var il = method2.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    type.DefineMethodOverride(method2, method);

    var concrete = type.CreateType();
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(concrete);
    int result = (int) concrete.GetMethod("Bar").Invoke(obj, null);
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's more likely to be the meaning of the question. I'll leave my answer around just in case it turns out to be useful, but I think you've got this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean CodeDOM? Reflection is used to *read* existing code, not *create* new code.

If you *do* mean CodeDOM, I believe you just need to create the `CodeMemberProperty` and set its `Attributes` property to include `MemberAttributes.Abstract`.